# Is it possible to get the BitmapFactory.Options instance associated with the bitmap returned by data.getExtras().get("data");

Tags: android

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
    }  
}
```

how can i get the BitmapFactory.Options instance associated with bitmap (photo).

Comment: There is not associated such thing with that Bitmap instance.

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();/***/
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;/****/

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);/****/

int height = options.outHeight;
int width = options.outWidth;/***/

im getting height and width of the bitmap through options

Comment: No. The only thing you can say is that you set width and height of your bitmap with the help of those options. After that there is no connection. Nobody, given your bitmap, can see how you created it.

Answer (score 1):

why `photo.getWidth()` and `photo.getHeight()` does not work for you?

If you have `Bitmap` under `"data"` key, you should get `Bitmap` reference and all available methods will be available.